# Select elements without specific nested elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply certain styles to all <p> elements that don't have nested <a> tags in them.
I tried to use the :not() selector like this:
    p:not(a){ /✱style✱/ }
but that did not affect anything. Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm still a beginner at this.

Comment: One css pseudo class I can think of is `:has`, but it is experimental. You can use javascript to achieve what you want.

Comment: Which browsers would support this?

Comment: None as per https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas